# Тернарная функция не равна if при DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, тернарный-оператор

Сегодня столкнулась вот с такой проблемой. Почему If  и тернарная функция не равны. Это работает:

```
     public class EmployeeClass
    {
        private DateTime? _Birthday;public DateTime? Birthday => _Birthday;

        public EmployeeClass(SPListItem item, SPList list)
        {
            if (item["Fld_EmployeeBirthday"] != null)
            {
                _Birthday = DateTime.Parse(item["Fld_EmployeeBirthday"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                _Birthday = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Это не работает:

```
_Birthday = item["Fld_EmployeeBirthday"] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item["Fld_EmployeeBirthday"].ToString()) : null;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где код_____?

Comment: Код должен вставляться текстом, а не картинкой. Создайте минимальный пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У _Birthday тип DateTime, ты пытаешься привести DateTime к null или DateTime. Поэтому тип DateTime необходимо обозначить как Nullable с помощью знака вопроса после типа. А null привести к Nullable
Что то должно быть вроде того:

```
DateTime? _Birthday; // Nullable<DateTime>
_BirthDay = <условие> ? Значение с типом DateTime : (DateTime?) null // null приводим к Nullable<DateTime>
```

Comment: (DateTime?) null - помогло, спасибо. ToString() Здесь нужен, потому что item[""] это object

Comment: А, мне показалось, что ты DateTime приводишь к стрингу - не заметил скобку в скрине